# GlobalLock Multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, memory

I SEEM to be having an issue with GlobalLock in my application. I say seem because I haven't been able to witness the issue by stepping through yet but when I let it run it breaks in one of two locations.

The app has multiple threads (say 2) simultaneously reading and writing bitmaps from PDF files. each thread handles a different file.

The first location it breaks I am reading a dib from the pdf to be OCRed. OCR is reading the characters on the bitmap and turning them into string data. The second location is when a new PDF is being created with the string data being added over the bitmap.

GlobalLock is being used on a HANDLE created by the following:

```
GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, uBytes);
```

I either get an AccessViolationError (always in the first instance) or I get GlobalLock returning a NULL pointer. (The second occurance)

It seems like one file is being read and another is having a copy written at the same time. There seems to be no pattern to which files it happens on.

Now I understand that the VC++ runtime has been multithreaded since 2005 (I am using VS2010 with 2008 toolchain). But is GlobalLock part of the runtime? It seems to me more like a platform independent thing.

I want to avoid just putting a CRITICAL_SECTION around globallock and globalunlock to get them to work, or at least not know why I am doing so.

Can anyone inform me better about GlobalLock/Unlock?
-A fish out of water

Comment: GlobalLock is an ancient Windows API.  The "Lock" has nothing to do with threads, it used to mean "lock address in memory".  Something that was necessary before Windows was a protected mode operating system with an MMU.  Not anymore, it is otherwise thread-safe.  Just sounds like heap corruption to me.

Comment: Im not seeing how it is possible at all... when it does happen the memory is invalid (I get ??? for all the members of my "locked" lpbitmapheader) and ?? all throughout the memory window. Ive been steping through it for the last 6 hours and havent been able to reproduce it without letting it run

Comment: My guess is that you are calling `GlobalReAlloc` to reallocate the block while another thread is assuming it's not going to move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the Global* heap routines are provided for compatibility with 16-bit windows. They still work, but there's no real reason to use them anymore, except for compatibility with routines that still use global heap object handles. Note that GlobalLock/GlobalUnlock are not threading locks - they prevent the memory from moving, but multiple threads can GlobalLock the same object at the same time.

That said, they are otherwise thread-safe; they take a heap lock internally, so there is no need to wrap your own locking around every Global* call. If you are having problems like this, it suggests you may be trying to `GlobalLock` a freed object, or you may be corrupting the heap (heap overflows, use-after-free, etc). You may also be missing thread synchronization on the *contents* of the heap object - the Global* API does not prevent multiple threads from accessing or modifying the same object at once.

Comment: I do realize the lock had to do with memory and not thread synchronization, but regardless this helps.